Set React app manifest.json start_url to dynamic uuid
I'm building a React App where users can have savable profiles. Each profile goes by https://myApp/uuid where uuid changes with every user profile.
How can I dynamically change my manifest.json file in order to make any profile installable as an app? (like https://myApp/1234)
By now, I've got start_url: "."in my manifest, and it only redirects to https://myApp when I save any profile to my phone.
If this is not possible with the start_url prop, how can I achieve that by other means?
